# Converting FRED dates from int to ddmmyy in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Based off the simple examples using the FRED API in the [Datafeed toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/datafeed/)

```
% setup connection c to fred
c = fred('http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/')

% pull data from fred using c
d = fetch(c,'DEXUSEU')
```

We are given a `DateRange` and a `Data` object with an int representing the `'yyyy-mm-dd'`

```
d.DateRange 
1999-01-04 to 2013-11-01

Head d.Data
%date   value
730124  1.1812
730125  1.1760
730126  1.1636
730127  1.1672
```

How can the integer representation of the date be converted to a [Matlab Date TimeSeries recognized type](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/fints.html) such as `'ddmmmyy hh:mm'` format so that it can be used with the time series object library? The hour and minutes are always 12:00 noon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
c = fred(url);
d = fetch(c,'DEXUSEU');

for i=1:length(d.Data)
    disp (datestr(d.Data(i,1),'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS'));
end
```

Comment: awesome slightly modifying the above to `disp (datestr(d.Data(i,1),'dd-mmm-yyyy 12:00'));` gives me exactly what i need thanks!

Comment: pleasure that's help.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = fetch(fred,'DEXUSEU');

disp (datestr(d.Data(:,1),'yyyy-mm-dd'));
```

Comment: Please avoid "you can try" answers, since they are not really answers. Use comments for that.

Comment: Sorry for that. Fixed!